# Expected min_ndim=4, found ndim= 2 in tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am developing an image classification model with images of shape (128,128,3). I have converted the image into numpy arrays but I haven't reshaped it. My model is

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(SpatialDropout2D(0.5))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=11, activation='relu', input_shape=(128, 128, 3)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(16, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(attention(return_sequences=False))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.6))
model.add(Dense(units=2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-5, beta_1=0.9, eta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False), metrics=['accuracy'])
model.build(input_shape=(128,128,3))
model.summary()
```

And the error I am getting is

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-97b1dd23f9b4> in <module>()
     18 model.add(SpatialDropout2D(0.5,input_shape=(128, 128, 3)))
     19 model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
---> 20 model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=11, activation='relu', input_shape=(128, 128, 3)))
     21 model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(16, return_sequences=True)))
     22 model.add(attention(return_sequences=False))

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py in assert_input_compatibility(input_spec, inputs, layer_name)
    237                          ', found ndim=' + str(ndim) +
    238                          '. Full shape received: ' +
--> 239                          str(tuple(shape)))
    240     # Check dtype.
    241     if spec.dtype is not None:

ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d_225 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 3)
```

Comment: the error doesn't correspond to the code snippet u posted

Comment: I am sorry. I have updated the error.

Comment: Remove model.build(...) and put input_shape=(128, 128, 3) in SpatialDropout2D (other errors will appear due to the wrong model structure)

Comment: Added input shape in SpatialDropout2D. I have updated the question with the new error which I am now getting in Conv2D.

Comment: Sure, GlobalPooling reduces to 2D how can you feed a Conv2D which expects 4D? Then  Conv2D produces 4D how can you feed an LSTM which expects 3D? (the error doesn't correspond to the code snippet u posted)